# Is it possible to convert an isz to an ISO image?

Tags: iso, format-conversion

What steps are necessary to convert a `.isz` file (compressed ISO image) to a standard ISO image using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by running [ultraiso](http://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/) in wine
[image]

**Links.**

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.isz
2. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=465785
3. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1197625
4. http://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/

Answer (score 3):

The `isz-tool`¹ worked fine for me. Use `./isz-tool.py isz2iso file.isz file.iso` to convert .isz image to .iso.

¹ — https://github.com/oserres/isz-tool

Comment: Looks cool , But I never had to touch isz image after 2012 :-)

Comment: I hope I won't had to touch these files again, but just thought it might be useful for other people :)